# It's given for $\left \{ A=\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} $=${1,\frac{1}{2}....}$. Why is $0$ accumulation point?

Tags: general-topology

It's given for  $\left \{  A=\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N} \right \} $$={1,\frac{1}{2}....}$.

Why is $0$ accumulation point?

It's never going to reach 0 because it's not in $\mathbb{N}?$

Comment: What's the "it" in your last sentence?

Comment: It can be approached to an arbitrary value so every neighbourhood of zero contains elements of A.

Comment: The point isn't that it cannot reach $0$, but that it can get **arbitrarily** close to $0$. Do you know what accumulation point means, or its formal definition?

Answer (score 0):

**Big Hint**

For all $m$, $$\left(\left]-\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m}\right[\backslash \{0\}\right)\cap A\neq \emptyset$$
for all $m$.

Answer (score 0):

An accumulation point does not have to lay inside the set. According to the definition of an accumulation point we have: "A point $x$ in $X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ different from $x$ itself."

Since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{n} = 0,$$
we have $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $|\frac{1}{n} - 0| < \epsilon.$

In other words if we take an open neighbourhood around $0$, say $O$, then there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that $(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset O$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. So $0$ is an accumulation point of $A$.